# How to order randomly data in a database table and insert the results into other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to order randomly data in a database table and insert into other table the results?
I mean that i have a list of rows in a table called house.then i need to to fetch those rows and order them randomly and insert into other table called winner.

How can i do this using php?

```
//***Menaharia and Studio Applicants***//
$aplSTMen=mysql_query('select * from applicant  where HouseType="Studio" AND SiteId="1"');  
$ApConutTotMenST = mysql_num_rows($aplSTMen);

$querysStudiomenaharia=mysql_query('select * from house  where HouseType="Studio" AND SiteId="1"');
$HoTotMenST = mysql_num_rows($querysStudiomenaharia);

//***THE NUMBER OF APPLICANTS ARE EQUAL TO THE NUMBER OF HOUSES***//
if( $HoTotMenST == $ApConutTotMenST) {
    while($rw1=mysql_fetch_array($aplSTMen)) {
        $ApplicantId= $rw1['ApplicantId'];
        $SiteId= $rw1['SiteId'];
        $ServiceType= $rw1['ServiceType'];
        $HouseType= $rw1['HouseType'];
        $PhysicalStatus= $rw1['PhysicalStatus'];
        $Gender= $rw1['Gender'];
        $MartialStatus=$rw1['MartialStatus'];   
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `condominium`.`winner` (`WinnerId`)VALUES ('$ApplicantId');");
    }

    $ararr[]=array($aplSTMen);

    while($rw1=mysql_fetch_array($querysStudiomenaharia)) {
        $ress=$rw1['reserved'];
        if( $ress== "no") {
            $BlockNo=$rw1['BlockNo'];
            $SiteId=$rw1['SiteId'];
            $HouseNumber=$rw1['HouseNumber'];
            $ararr[]=$HouseNumber;
            echo $HouseNumber."<br\>";

            /*$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `condominium`.`winner` (`WinnerId`, `SiteId`, `HouseNumber`, `BlockNo`) 
                    VALUES ('$ApplicantId', '$SiteId',$HouseNumber , '$BlockNo');");*/
        }
    }
}
```

i have tried the above but it is not working.

Comment: Please edit your question's format. It's in a mess.

Comment: There are two reasons that your plan appears flawed.  First, you want to duplicate data by copying rows from one table to another.  Second, you care about the order in which records are inserted.  Given that you can sort query results, the order of the records in the actual table should never matter.

Comment: DanBracuk is right. If you realy need that anyways, read about http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html and `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 1):

No need to copy the data in memory. If you want a psuedo-random order, just add " ORDER BY rand();" to the end of your MySQL queries.

Comment: what i need is there are applicants for condominium house and there is registers house,to select applicants and houses  randomly until the number of house is finished then i need to register the house number and applicant id in the table winner.

Comment: I fail to see how this changes what I posted. A MySQL query with ORDER BY rand() will output results in random order. You can use this at the end of a INSERT...SELECT statement, and have that statement within a stored procedure you call with PHP. You can then get the inserted values out from the stored procedure and use on the page.

Comment: i have able to register applicants randomly to the winner table,but i did not able to assign houses to the winner.the ORDER BY RAND() is work perfectly.